# Header pin plastic sliding off stripboard

Tags: soldering, pins

When I was soldering header pins onto a stripboard I noticed the plastic in the middle of the pins had become extremely loose to the point if I turn the board upside down the pins will fall off the stripboard.

What I want to know is how do I stop this from happening or is this what usually happens?

I’m using a 5 to 10 year old 40 watt soldering iron with a lot of grime on the iron

And these are the header pins I’m using. The plastic being the black bits→[image]

This is where I bought the pins: http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/254mm-pin-strip-jw59

Comment: You're using way too much heat. For starters, get a good temperature-controlled iron.

Comment: @DaveTweed The iron I'm using can only barely melt the solder but I know somewhere I can use a temperature controlled iron so I'll try it at a low heat and see if that helps, thanks

Comment: I had this happen to me before. You need to press the tip of the iron against the pad on the PCB, close to but not directly touching the pin.

Comment: @Justin in order to avoid cold solder joints, you really should heat up BOTH the pin AND the pad by touching both with the iron. It should be done quickly, though, so as to avoid the issue the OP is having

Answer (score 2, accepted):

40W is MUCH too much heat for small pins. The reason it barely melts the solder is because you haven't kept it clean and tinned, and the tip has probably burned. I suggest getting a new iron and TIN the tip IMMEDIATELY, while it's heating up for the first time. A 15-watt iron will be sufficient for soldering pin headers like you showed in your question. A tinned tip will allow the heat to be transferred to the pad and to the pin, allowing solder to flow properly.

Right now you're using way too much heat, and it's melting the plastic around the pins. Soldering of a single pin should only take a couple of seconds maximum with a proper clean, tinned tip. That is not enough time for the plastic to melt.

Comment: The iron 40W iron I'm talking about in this post is a school iron so I wouldn't be able to replace the tip but there's somewhere else where I live I can use a temperature controlled soldering iron so when ever I need to solder parts similar to those pins I'll use that iron rather than the 40W ones. For the temperature controlled iron what temperature would you suggest?

Comment: Sounds like a good plan! For most of my projects 500 degrees F is sufficient. You may have to turn it up a bit for soldering large things (heat sink tabs, etc) but I generally don't go above 650F